# How can I use Gravity forms to build login and registration for external website?

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, gravity-forms-plugin

I have built a few forms that will be used to sign in and register for external applications from my website.  I have all the correct naming fields in the Gravity forms but can't get the gform_after_submission to work.  It keeps submitting my form instead of posting to the form action I specified.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_4', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

$post_url = 'http://mythirdpartsite.com/login.asp';
$body = array(
    'username' => rgar( $entry, '5' ), 
    'password' => rgar( $entry, '6' ), 
    );

$request = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );

}
?>
```

For reference:

4 - Form ID
5 & 6 - Entry ID's

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Gravity Forms has a registration add-on that I've used before that works great & was easy to set up. You do have to pay, but it's well worth it as far as saving time goes.

Comment: Thank you.  We ended up using jquery top send the entry id fields' data to the thrid-party website and it works great.  For some reason it would not recognise the gravity form data. Will look at the add-on though for future use